# Android NDK undefined reference to ASensorEventQueue_registerSensor

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, sensors

I try to register a sensor via NDK and it works until I try to use ASensorEventQueue_registerSensor. I do it like in the following code:

```
#include <android/sensor.h>
[...]
auto status = ASensorEventQueue_registerSensor(accelerometerEventQueue, accelerometer, SENSOR_REFRESH_PERIOD_US,SENSOR_BATCH_REPORT_TIME);
[...]
```

My CMakeLists.txt looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp )


target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib
                       android
                       log)
```

I can use functions like `ASensorEventQueue_enableSensor`or `ASensorEventQueue_setEventRate` but I am not able to run the app when using `ASensorEventQueue_registerSensor` due to undefined reference error.

By the way I can see the function in the included header file so this shouldn't be the problem. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is that you're missing a `find_library` for liblog and libandroid. Add the following before `target_link_libraries`:

```
find_library(android android)
find_library(log log)
```

However I'm not sure that's needed.

The other possibility is that your `minSdkVersion` is lower than 26. `ASensorEventQueue_registerSensor` was not added until O, so it can't be linked unless your `minSdkVersion` is at least 26.

Comment: Sorry for the very late answer. Indeed I chose 19 as minSDK. So this seems to be the reason. Thank you very much for the explanation!